# Histogram in R not looking how I expect

Tags: r, histogram

So I'm just making a basic histogram to represent the probability mass function of a die roll.  I figure this should be easy, just

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
hist(x)
```

seems like it should work, but when I run this, the lowest bin has twice the frequency.  Pretty clearly, values 1 and 2 are getting put into the same bin, but I don't see why or how to correct for this.  Tried setting `right=FALSE` but that just shifted where the overlap occurs: now on the right.

Can someone explain why I'm getting the unexpected result and how to fix it please?

Comment: You probably just want a `barplot` rather than a histogram when dealing with discrete values, e.g. -  `barplot(table(x))` If you absolutely must use a histogram, set the `breaks=` argument - `hist(x,breaks=seq(0.5,6.5,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple solution:

```
x <- 1:6 # The same as your x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
hist(x, breaks=0:6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the default vector function creates the breaks but you can override them explicitly.  For example,

```
hist(c(1,2,3,4,5), breaks=c(.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5))
```

will give you the evenly distributed histogram[image]